# Limit of non-negative non increasing function is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: functional-analysis

So the problem is: Suppose $g_n \in C[a,b]$ is a sequence of non-negative functions such that $g_n(x)$ is a non-increasing sequence for each $x \in R$. Show that the limiting function $\displaystyle g(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} g_n(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable.

I think I should somehow use monotone convergence theorem but I am not sure how to apply the theorem here.

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Alternatively, apply the monotone convergence theorem to the sequence of functions $\left(g_1-g_n\right)_n$.

Comment: I guess it should be "for each $x\in[a,b]$", not "for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$".

Answer (score 1):

Well, the limit $g$ is measurable, as a limit of continuous functions, it is also non-negative, as a limit of non-negative functions, and as
$$
g_1\ge g\ge 0,
$$
then 
$$
\int_a^b |g|\,dx= \int_a^b g\,dx\le \int_a^b g_1\,dx<\infty,
$$
as hence $g$ is Lebesgue integrable.

By the way, $g$ is also continuous!